# How can i convert an array like object into JSON objects which I will be able to save into firebase database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase

I have a function returning an array of objects:

```
() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table.inzeraty"))
    .map(offer => {
      const image = offer.querySelector('img.obrazek')
      const desc = offer.querySelector('div.popis')
      const location = offer.querySelector('tbody:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)')
      return ({
        title: offer.querySelector('span.nadpis > a').innerText.trim(),
        price: offer.querySelector('span.cena > b').innerText.trim(),
        image: image ? image.src : '',
        desc: desc ? desc.innerText.trim() : '',
        location: location ? location.innerText.trim() : '',
        link: offer.querySelector('span.nadpis > a').href
      })
    })
```

The function returns Array that looks like this:

```
[ { title: 'Kentoya Viking 125',
price: '22 000 Kč',
image: 'https://www.bazos.cz/img/1t/363/94935363.jpg',
desc: 'Prodám skútr Kentoya.',
location: 'Karlovy Vary\n360 01',
link: 'https://motorky.bazos.cz/inzerat/94935363/Kentoya-Viking-125.php' },
{ title: 'KYMCO MOVIE XL 150',
price: '15 000 Kč',
image: 'https://www.bazos.cz/img/1t/377/94934377.jpg?t=1538135827',
desc: 'Rv.2002. najeto.16800km.',
location: 'Praha 1\n110 00',
link: 'https://motorky.bazos.cz/inzerat/94934377/KYMCO-MOVIE-XL-150.php' } ]
```

I would like to know if I am somehow able to convert the result into a json file which I would be able to save into firebase database.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a JSON only. If you want a stringified version you can always wrap this in `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Ok, but I am still not able to push this into firebase database. Could you please suggest how should i do it using the set() method?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need JSON to store to firebase when you use the firebase SDK library

Comment: @TadeasHort I don't see where in your code you interact with Firebase. What problem do you have when you save that JSON to Firebase?